# Solving the water jug problem

Tags: math, computer-science, theory

While reading through some [lecture notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/NR/rdonlyres/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-042JFall-2005/E7AB2626-FB19-480E-95F5-A9C23C2BD885/0/ln6.pdf) on preliminary number theory, I came across the solution to 
water jug problem (**with two jugs)** which is summed as thus:

Using the property of the G.C.D of two numbers that GCD(a,b) is the smallest possible linear combination of a and b, and hence a certain quantity Q is only measurable by the 2 jugs, iff Q is a n*GCD(a,b), since Q=sA + tB, where:

```
n = a positive integer
A = capacity of jug A
B=  capacity of jug B
```

And, then the method to the solution is discussed

Another model of the solution is to model the various *states* as a state-space search problem as often resorted to  in Artificial Intelligence.

My question is: What other known methods exist which models the solution, and how? Google didn't throw up much.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly for 2 Jug Problem

```
Q = A * x + B * y
```

Q = Gallons you need.

**Note:** *The Q must be a multiple of Gcd(A,B) else there is no solution. If Gcd(A,B) == 1, There is a solution for Any Q.*

1) **Method 1 :**
[Extended Euclid's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) will solve it faster than any Graph Algorithm.

2) **Method 2:**
Here's a *Naive Approach.* (note, this can throw 2 solutions, You'll have to choose which is shorter)

The Problem in question can be simply solved by `repeatedly` Fill from one bucket A to another bucket B (order doesnt matter) until it fills up with the amount you want...ofcoz, when a bucket fillsup, you empty it and continue.

```
    A = 3, B = 4 and Q = 2
```

Repeatedly Fill A->B

```
    A B
   ######
    0 0
    4 0
    1 3
    1 0
    0 1
    4 1
    2 3 <-Solution
```

Lets try and observe what happens if we go the other way round,
Fill B->A

```
A  B
#####
0  0
0  3
3  0
3  3
4  2 <- Solution
```

In this case filling B->A gives us the goal state faster than A->B

**Generic N Jugs**
Here's an interesting [paper](http://algo2006.csie.dyu.edu.tw/paper/3/A34.pdf)

Comment: Deciding which one to fill to first: does this  - "IF(Q is b/w A AND B) THEN max(A, B) ELSE min(A, B)" help actually?

Comment: @AMAR, I don't think so. Can't say for sure. Do you have any proof?

Comment: Nope. It was a question. I had tried it in a problem with hit and trial to smaller 5-6 pairs. Not sure if it works for all.

Comment: Is it possible to have jugs with such volumes that it takes same number of steps for both the approaches: filling A first and filling B first??

Comment: @st0le The link to the paper (in the end) is a dead link.

Answer (score 3):

An amazing and amusing approach (for 3 jugs) is through *[barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_(mathematics))* (really!), as described at the always brilliant website Cut-the-Knot: [Barycentric coordinates: A Curious Application](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/glasses.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is often amenable to [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) techniques. I've ofetn seen this specific problem used as an example in operations research courses. One nice step-by-step description is [here](http://www.tutor.ms.unimelb.edu.au/pub/pub_dp.html).

Comment: The link (in the end) is a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

The search space method is what I would've suggested. I made a program to solve generic water jugs problems using a BFS. Could send it to you if you wish.

Comment: Yes, do share here please.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem during one of my studies. As you, and as st0le said here, I found as answer to the problem the Extended Euclide's algorithm. But this answer do not satisfied me, because I think it's a quantitative answer, not a qualitative one (that is, the algorithm does not say what step to take to reach the result).

I think I found a different solution to the problem that always reach the result with the minimum number of steps.

Here it is:

1. Check problem's feasibility:

   - Q is a multiple of the MCD(A,B);
   - Q is <= max(A,B).
2. Choose the service jug (that is, the one you will refill with the pump). Supposing A > B (you can easily find which jug is the bigger one):

   ```
   if(Q is multiple of B)
       return B

   a_multiplier = 1
   b_multiplier = 1
   difference = A - B
   a_multiple = A
   b_multiple = B
   while(|difference| differs Q)
       if b_multiple < a_multiple
           b_multiple = b_multiplier + 1
           b_multiple = b_multiplier * B
       else
           a_multiple = a_multiplier + 1
           a_multiple = a_multiplier * A

       difference = a_multiple - b_multiple

   if(difference < 0)
       return B
   else
       return A
   ```
3. start the filling process:

   - fill with the pump the service jug (if empty)
   - fill the other jug using the service one
   - check fullness of the other jug and, in case, empty it
   - stop when the bigger jug contains Q

Below you find a very naive implementation of the algorithm in c++. Feel free to reuse it, or improve it as you need.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

unsigned int mcd(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    // using the Euclide's algorithm to find MCD(a,b)
    unsigned int a_n = a;
    unsigned int b_n = b;
    while(b_n != 0) {
        unsigned int a_n1 = b_n;
        b_n = a_n % b_n; 
        a_n = a_n1;
    }
    return a_n;
}

unsigned int max(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

unsigned int min(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    return a > b ? b : a;
}

void getServiceJugIndex(unsigned int capacities[2], unsigned int targetQty, unsigned int &index) {
    unsigned int biggerIndex = capacities[0] < capacities[1] ? 1 : 0;
    unsigned int smallerIndex = 1 - biggerIndex;
    if(targetQty % capacities[smallerIndex] == 0) {
        // targetQty is a multiple of the smaller jug, so it's convenient to use this one
        // as 'service' jug
        index = smallerIndex;
        return;
    }

    unsigned int multiples[2] = {capacities[0], capacities[1]};
    unsigned int multipliers[2] = {1, 1};
    int currentDifference = capacities[0] - capacities[1];
    while(abs(currentDifference) != targetQty) {
        if(multiples[smallerIndex] < multiples[biggerIndex])
            multiples[smallerIndex] = capacities[smallerIndex] * ++multipliers[smallerIndex];
        else
            multiples[biggerIndex] = capacities[biggerIndex] * ++multipliers[biggerIndex];

        currentDifference = multiples[biggerIndex] - multiples[smallerIndex];
    }

    index = currentDifference < 0 ? smallerIndex : biggerIndex;
}

void print_step(const char *message, unsigned int capacities[2], unsigned int fillings[2]) {
    printf("%s\n\n", message);
    for(unsigned int i = max(capacities[0], capacities[1]); i > 0; i--) {
        if(i <= capacities[0]) {
            char filling[9];
            if(i <= fillings[0])
                strcpy(filling, "|=====| ");
            else
                strcpy(filling, "|     | ");
            printf("%s", filling);
        } else {
            printf("        ");
        }
        if(i <= capacities[1]) {
            char filling[8];
            if(i <= fillings[1])
                strcpy(filling, "|=====|");
            else
                strcpy(filling, "|     |");
            printf("%s", filling);
        } else {
            printf("       ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("------- -------\n\n");
}

void twoJugsResolutor(unsigned int capacities[2], unsigned int targetQty) {
    if(capacities[0] == 0 && capacities[1] == 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Both jugs have 0 l capacity.\n");
        return;
    }
    // 1. check feasibility
    //  1.1. calculate MCD and verify targetQty is reachable
    unsigned int mcd = ::mcd(capacities[0], capacities[1]);
    if ( targetQty % mcd != 0 ||
    //  1.2. verify that targetQty is not more than max capacity of the biggest jug
            targetQty > max(capacities[0], capacities[1])) {
        printf("The target quantity is not reachable with the available jugs\n");
        return;
    }
    // 2. choose 'service' jug
    unsigned int serviceJugIndex;
    getServiceJugIndex(capacities, targetQty, serviceJugIndex);
    unsigned int otherJugIndex = 1 - serviceJugIndex;
    unsigned int finalJugIndex = capacities[0] > capacities[1] ? 0 : 1;
    // 3. start fill process
    unsigned int currentFilling[2] = {0, 0};
    while(currentFilling[finalJugIndex] != targetQty) {
        // 3.1 fill with the pump the service jug (if needed)
        if(currentFilling[serviceJugIndex] == 0) {
            currentFilling[serviceJugIndex] = capacities[serviceJugIndex];
            print_step("Filling with the pump the service jug", capacities, currentFilling);
        }

        // 3.2 fill the other jug using the service one
        unsigned int thisTimeFill = min(currentFilling[serviceJugIndex], capacities[otherJugIndex] - currentFilling[otherJugIndex]);
        currentFilling[otherJugIndex] += thisTimeFill;
        currentFilling[serviceJugIndex] -= thisTimeFill;
        print_step("Filling the other jug using the service one", capacities, currentFilling);
        // 3.3 check fullness of the other jug and, in case, empty it
        if(currentFilling[otherJugIndex] == capacities[otherJugIndex]) {
            currentFilling[otherJugIndex] = 0;
            print_step("Empty the full jug", capacities, currentFilling);
        }
    }
    printf("Done\n");
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc < 4)
        return -1;
    unsigned int jugs[] = {atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])};
    unsigned int qty = atoi(argv[3]);

    twoJugsResolutor(jugs, qty);
}
```

I don't know if there is any mathematical concept behind the process I described to choose the right jug to minimize the number of needed steps, I use it as an heuristic.

I hope this can help you.